# How to feed the output of a barcode scanner into two systems?

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a ds4308 barcode scanner and have to feed the output of a scanner into two systems like one PC and one Raspberry Pi.
How to do it?

Comment: What exactly is the Problem? 
Do you not know how to Programm in the SerialPort class for receiving Data from the BarcodeReader, or do you not know how to send it to the Rasperry?
What have you tried? I cant see the exact problem out of your Question

Comment: It's all about how you design your system and both applications. Since there is only one scanner hardware, you can only connect to either one computer. Create an application that communicates with the scanner on the computer you decide to connect to. To and from the application on the other computer, you need to feed the barcode data using the protocol between the applications that you define yourself. In addition, you may need to change the protocol depending on how you connect the two computers.